# Bash for loop over string containing a '*'

Tags: bash, environment-variables

I got a problem iterating over a environment variable containing a list of file patterns.

Example:
    "FILEPATTERN=*.xml *.log"

Code:

```
local log_file_pattern=(${FILEPATTERN})
for (( i=0; i < ${#log_file_pattern}; i++ ))
do
  pattern="${log_file_pattern[$i]}"
  ... some more code ...
done
```

I always get:

- pattern=*.xml on first iteration
- pattern=anaconda-post.log on second iteration

How can I stop the loop from interpreting *.log?

Comment: How are you setting `FILEPATTERN`?

Comment: What are you trying to do? give us the full picture, you might have a design problem. What are you going to do, eventually, with these globs?

Note that your command is equivalent to `for f in ${FILEPATTERN}; do pattern=$f; ... some more code ...; done`. If you really really want to turn globs off, you can `set -f` at the beginning of your function, and then turn globs back on at then end with `set +f`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe `FILEPATTERN` is set to `*.xml *.log`

The problem is in this line:

```
local log_file_pattern=(${FILEPATTERN})
```

Since you are not using double quotes around `${FILEPATTERN}`, shell globbing is in effect.  Seems like there are no files matching `*.xml` in your directory whereas `*.log` does expand to some file names.  That's why your array element 0 gets set to `*.xml` and element 1 gets set to `anaconda-post.log`.

You can solve your problem by using `read` command to load your array, with a herestring:

```
local log_file_pattern
read -r -a log_file_pattern <<< "$FILEPATTERN"
```

Which loads `*.xml` to element 0 and `*.log` to element 1 of your array, without globbing.